# Beginners JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript.
I've worked my work through Learning JavaScript (o'reilly) but am just trying to make my first JavaScript.

I thought it best to work on something I'm interested in and as it turned out is fairly complicated.

I'm basically trying to simulate (eventually) a situation in Space Hulk (Boardgame) where a Genestealer has 12 steps between him and the Space Marine.
On the first step its 6 on either dice to kill the Genestealer, and after that 5 or 6 to kill.
The gun jams if the number on the dice is the same.

I'm just trying to emulate the first step here. I think the problem is with **jamCheck**.

Basically this outputs as always true, even if I change it to != it always shows gun jammed.

I wondered if the variable needed to be passed into another local variable, but it works for killCheck without having to do this. (and I tried it, although I may be doing it wrong)

It is completely possible there is something really simple wrong here.

I hope you can help, or point me in the right direction.

Many thanks!

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>SH</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[

    function diceRoll1() {
       iValue = Math.random(); // random number between 0 and 1
       iValue *= 6; // multiply by 6 to move the decimal
       iValue = Math.floor(iValue)+1; // round to nearest integer. +1 to 1-6.
       var roll1 = iValue;
       document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = 'Dice roll 1 : ' + roll1;
       killCheck (roll1);
       jamCheck (roll1);
       return;
    }

    function diceRoll2() {
       iValue = Math.random(); // random number between 0 and 1
       iValue *= 6; // multiply by 6 to move the decimal
       iValue = Math.floor(iValue)+1; // round to nearest integer. +1 to 1-6.
       var roll2 = iValue;
       document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = 'Dice roll 2 : ' + roll2;
       killCheck (roll2);
       jamCheck (roll2);
       return;  
    }

    function killCheck(roll1,roll2){
        if (roll1==6 || roll2==6)
        {
        document.getElementById('kill').innerHTML = 'GS KILLED';
        }
        return;
    }

    function jamCheck(roll1,roll2){
        if (roll1 == roll2)
        {
        document.getElementById('jam').innerHTML = 'GUN JAMMED';
        }
        return;
    }   

    //]]>
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="diceRoll1();diceRoll2();killCheck();jamCheck();">
      <p id="result1">Dice roll 1</p>
      <p id="result2">Dice roll 2</p>
      <p id="kill">GS ALIVE</p>
      <p id="jam">GUN FINE</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**EDIT:** I eventually got there with a lot of help from a friend; here is the current code:

```
...
function getDiceValue() {
var diceValue = Math.random(); 
diceValue *= 6;
diceValue = Math.floor(diceValue) + 1; 
return diceValue;
}

function killCheck(roll1, roll2) {
if (roll1 === 6 || roll2 === 6) {
document.getElementById('kill').innerHTML = 'GS KILLED';
}
return;
}

function jamCheck(roll1, roll2){
if (roll1 === roll2) {
document.getElementById('jam').innerHTML = 'GUN JAMMED';
}
return;
}

function rollDice() {
var roll1 = getDiceValue(),
roll2 = getDiceValue();
document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = 'Dice roll 1 : ' + roll1;
document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = 'Dice roll 2 : ' + roll2;
killCheck (roll1, roll2);
jamCheck (roll1, roll2);
}
//]]>
...
<body onload="rollDice();">
```

Comment: just an unrelated note, don't use empty-returns at the end of a functions (they will return nothing anyway). The only reason why you would ever use an empty-return is to stop the function (similar to a break on a loop)

Comment: Here's a handy die-roll function if you want to clean things up a bit: function rollDie(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
} 6-sided example: rollDie(1,6);

Comment: @ajax333221 I read that would return it to killCheck and JamCheck, is it not needed at all?

Comment: @pdizz thanks I'll give that a go, I thought there must be a way to cut that down!

Comment: @ajax333221 Just re read Dr.Dredel answer and saw he mentioned I need to return roll1 etc.

Comment: @snoopyj if you're familiar with any higher level programming (C, C++, Java, C#, etc), you'll recognize a few differences with the return in JavaScript.  every function in JS is a void function until you tell it otherwise by returning a value.  The value returned by *every* function is `undefined` until you say otherwise.  Therefore `return;` at the end of a function doesnt really do anything, just like having a return statement in a void method in c#.  Dont forget to accept an answer below if it helped you :)  Pick the most accurate one to your knowledge.

Comment: @Kirean Sadly I'm not familiar with higher level programming, which is probably partly why I'm having trouble getting my head around what's needed :)

I understand your comment on the values being undefined though, which explains why it was true!

I still haven't managed to crack this even with the helpful comments from everyone, I'll give it another look but obviously I must still be doing something wrong!

You and Dr.Dredel have been very helpful in particular, should I wait until I've completely resolved this?

Comment: @snoopyj no worries.  Everyone starts somewhere!  And when you find a solution that has worked for you, just accept that answer.  Personally I think Dr.Dredel is more indepth than my answer.  But whichever gets you to the solution the most is the "correct" one.

Comment: Thanks again @Kirean I've got there in the end with a little help from a friend, I'll update my main post with what I changed. I've selected Dr.Dredel but you were both very helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math.floor() rounds down (think about the name... ceil rounds up) if you REALLY want to round to the "nearest" integer you need to use Math.round().

In your case if you multiply by 6 and round down you'll never get a number higher than 5.

I suspect this is your problem, though I only glanced at your code, so, forgive me if that's just one mistake and not the cause of your issue.

[Edit] upon further reflection, disregard the above.  The problem is that your methods expects 2 parameters but you're only passing in one.

I think you're misunderstanding the way parameter passing works.

`jamCheck(p1, p2){}`  what you name these is not relevant. These labels only exist INSIDE your method. I suspect that what is confusing you is that you're using the same labels for the variables you're passing in, as well as the ones in your method.  So, when you call the method jamCheck(roll1) it can't do what it needs to cause it's designed to work on 2 variables.  Beyond that whatever result you're getting is just the browser trying to make up for code whose syntax is broken.  In languages like C or Java you wouldn't even be able to compile such code; You'd be pointed at these lines as not making any sense, by the compiler.

So, the solution is (something like)...

```
var roll1,roll2;

roll1 = diceRoll1();
roll2 = diceRoll2();
jamCheck(roll1,roll2);
killCheck(roll1,roll2);
```

But in your diceRoll methods the last thing you'll need to do is `return roll1;` (or roll2 respectively)

And look to kirean's answer for how to wrap this all up in an init method, so that you're not calling 4 (or more) methods from the body's onload callback.

Answer (score 1):

Youre doing a couple things wrong here, the first is confusing function scoped variables with global scoped variables.

this function

```
function jamCheck(roll1,roll2){
    if (roll1 == roll2)
    {
    document.getElementById('jam').innerHTML = 'GUN JAMMED';
    }
    return;
}
```

expects two parameters, but you are passing in *none* here `body onload="...jamcheck()"`

as a result, undefined is equal to undefined, so of course its true.

You need a wrapper function similar to this

```
function executeGame(){
   var dice1 = rollDice1();
   var dice2 = rollDice2();

   jamCheck(dice1, dice2)
}
```

And then call this function on body onload.

Comment: Awesome thank you everyone! A good few things for me to try! I'll give them a go and get back to you all. I have much to learn!